# How is it that my React component understands the 'children' property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

For some time, when writing wrappers, I was using:

```
import React from "react";

export default props => (
  <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{props.children}</div>
);
```

But just a seconds ago I came across this cool technique:

```
import React from "react";

export default props => <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} {...props} />;
```

How does it work under the hood, I mean, is `div` also a `React` component that understands `children` attribute?

This code also works:

```
export default ({ children }) => (
  <div children={children} style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} />
);
```

Comment: `{props.children}` does something very different from `{...props}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. The special prop 'children'

`children` is a special prop that React passes automatically to your components.

You can use this special prop to compose components:

```
const ComposedComponent = props => <div>{props.children}</div>
```

- If `children` is a string, React will just write the text inside your component.
- If `children` is another component, it will generate the code to make this component inside your first component (for instance, a `<span>` inside a `<div>`).
- If `children` is an array of components, it will generate the code to make all these components inside your first component (for instance, several `<li>` inside a `<ul>`).

Of course, the `children` components can have their own `children` components, so React will recursively loop through each child to generate all the nested components.

---

## 2. JSX, React.createElement and children

`JSX` provides syntactic sugar for `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`.

**a.** When you write this code

```js
export default ({ children }) => (
  <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} children={children} />
);
```

It is actually transformed in

```js
export default ({ children }) => React.createElement('div', {
    style: { fontWeight: 'bold' },
    children: children,
});
```

**b.** And this code

```js
export default props => <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} {...props} />;
```

is transformed in

```js
export default props => React.createElement('div', {
    style: { fontWeight: 'bold' },
    ...props, // this extracts children into the object, ie. children: children
});
```

So these two examples generate the same code under the hood.

**c.** The transformation of your first example is a bit different.

This code

```js
export default props => (
  <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{props.children}</div>
);
```

is transformed in

```js
export default props => React.createElement('div', {
    style: { fontWeight: 'bold' },
}, props.children); // it uses createElement's third parameter
```

But for `React.createElement`, having a prop `children` in the second parameter (like in **a.** and **b.**) is equivalent to passing the children in the third parameter (**c.**). It generates the same component.

---

References:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html